# h5py read time has random and harsh flucuations in read speed

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I am using `h5py` to read in pre-processed data to be fed into a convolutional neural network. All input images are the same size. I am using the following read/write syntax:

```
# Read
with h5py.File() as x:
    numpy_array = x['key'][:]

# Write
x = h5py.File(data_path)
x.create_dataset('key', data = numpy_array)
x.close()
```

My dataset has around 500 samples. For some odd reason, the first `N` number of iterations (N seems to vary) of training, where at each iteration I read in an `hdf5` file, I see the following performance time

> load data time:  0.10571813583374023

But then, all of a sudden, at the `N+1` iteration, loading data starts to take much more time.

> load data time:  1.5208463668823242

Any ideas what could be causing this? Once the performance shift happens, it never turns back. This doesn't make any sense to me given that all of the files are the same size. Even once I go through all samples and get back to the beginning, files that were originally being read quickly are taking much longer to load.

Edit: Here is exact code sample, using `h5py.File() as x` syntax, and sample output behavior.

```
def train(points_h5f, img_h5f, labels_h5f):
    '''
    Populating dictionaries used by external libraries later on in code
    '''

    for i in range(num_samples):
        a = time.time()

        # Load points
        points = {}
        points['dict_key'] = {'points':points_h5f['points/point_{}'.format(i)][:]}

        # Load images
        images = {}
        for cam in camera_sensors:
            prop_d = {}
            for prop in camera_prop:
                prop_d[prop] = img_h5f['{}/{}/{}_{}'.format(cam,prop,prop,i)][:]                  
            images[cam] = prop_d

        # Load labels
        labels = []
        for j in range(num_labels):
            labels.append(labels_h5f['label_groups/label_{}_{}'.format(i,j)][:])

        b = time.time()

        print('Iteration: {} \nload data time: {}\n'.format(i, b-a))

with h5py.File('path/all_points.hdf5', 'r') as points_h5f:
        with h5py.File('path/all_images.hdf5', 'r') as img_h5f:
            with h5py.File('path/all_labels.hdf5', 'r') as labels_h5f:
                train(points_h5f, img_h5f, labels_h5f)


> output

>Iteration: 0
load data time: 0.09873628616333008

Iteration: 1
load data time: 0.09973263740539551

Iteration: 2
load data time: 0.09973430633544922

Iteration: 3
load data time: 0.1057431697845459
.
.
.

Iteration: 125
load data time: 0.09771347045898438

Iteration: 126
load data time: 0.24407505989074707

Iteration: 127
load data time: 1.0163114070892334

Iteration: 128
load data time: 1.0114076137542725

Iteration: 129
load data time: 1.0284936428070068

Iteration: 130
load data time: 1.1249558925628662

Iteration: 131
load data time: 1.025432825088501

.
.
. 

Iteration: 500
load data time: 1.114523423498758
```

Comment: How big is each sample array? (and how big is the resulting HDF5 file?) Is each sample saved to a separate dataset (aka `x[key1]`, `x[key2]`, `x[key3]`, etc? Or are you adding new sample data to the end of an existing dataset?

Comment: Another question: Do you open/close the file for writing on each 'load data' loop? If so, that may be the culprit. I ran 2 tests. In the first, I used `with h5py.File() as x:` to hold the file open for the entire data writing process. It shows no performance degradation. The second test opens/closes on every loop. It shows time fluctuations similar to yours.

Comment: @kcw78 Thanks for the response. See post edit where I give exact code snippet. FYI, I tried changing the _open file -> close file_ structure in my code to with `h5py.File() as x` and found I had the same issue. Did I interpret your comment correctly? Meaning, would going from `x = h5py.File('path')` to `h5py.File() as x` have been your suggestion?

Comment: Yes, you interpreted my comment correctly. The code you added to the post reflects the _open file -> close file_ method inside the different loops. After posting my 2nd comment, I realized I ran my test cases on a drive with OneDrive synch enabled. I've discovered that it can cause I/O degradation. I reran my tests on a different drive, and could not reproduce the time fluctuations you experienced. I will post my tests and you can run them for yourself. Maybe they will help you diagnose the bottleneck.

Comment: @kcw78 Thanks for the tip. Also, I did have OneDrive on which after turning off did speed things up a bit. However, I am still facing this problem. I think my question was unclear so I have added a sample output to this post as well as updated the sample code with the syntax you suggested. I am seeing an over 10x performance drop out of nowhere and once it happens, it never goes away.

Comment: After reviewing your code, nothing obvious jumps out. You may need to profile to find the bottleneck. Before you do that, modify your ecample to read each h5 file individually. Create 3 separate `train--` functions; one each to read `points_h5f`, then `img_h5f`, then `labels_h5f`. That way you can isolate if it's one dataset the causes the problem, or all 3, or if when you have all 3 open at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 simple tests that create an HDF5 file with 1000 float arrays of shape(200,200,3).

> - With Method 1, I consistently get 0.17-0.20 sec/100 datasets written.
> - With Method 2, I consistently get 0.23-0.25 sec/100 datasets written.

Times are writing to HDD. Expect faster results on an SDD.
Method 2 is slightly slower, but not as much as you are seeing.

**Method 1: Open HDF5 once using `with -- as:`**

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import time

num = 1000

with h5py.File('SO_59555208_1.h5', 'w') as h5f:

    start = time.clock()
    for cnt in range(num):
        if cnt % (num/10) == 0 and cnt > 1:
            print ('dataset count: {}/{}'.format(cnt, num) )
            print ('Elapsed time =', (time.clock() - start) ) 
            start = time.clock()

        ds_name = 'key_' + str(cnt) 
        # Create sample image data and add to a dataset
        img_data = np.random.rand(200*200*3,1).reshape(200,200,3)
        dset = h5f.create_dataset(ds_name, data=img_data )

print ('dataset count: {}/{}'.format(cnt, num) )
print ('Elapsed time =', (time.clock() - start) ) 
print ('DONE')
```

**Method 2: Open/Close HDF5 to add each dataset**

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import time

num = 1000

start = time.clock()
for cnt in range(num):
    if cnt % (num/10) == 0 and cnt > 1:
        print ('dataset count: {}/{}'.format(cnt, num) )
        print ('Elapsed time =', (time.clock() - start) ) 
        start = time.clock()
    h5f = h5py.File('SO_59555208_m.h5', 'a')     
    ds_name = 'key_' + str(cnt) 
    # Create sample image data and add to a dataset
    img_data = np.random.rand(200*200*3,1).reshape(200,200,3)
    dset = h5f.create_dataset(ds_name, data=img_data )
    h5f.close()

print ('dataset count: {}/{}'.format(cnt, num) )
print ('Elapsed time =', (time.clock() - start) ) 
print ('DONE')
```